# Definición correcta de la cadena de conexion en el archivoappsetings.json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

Compilo el proyecto y no me despliega error desde la aplicación, lo puedo ver solo si entro a la consola de Chrome.

El programa debería mostrar un json con el id y el nombre de una categoría.

Esta es mi definición de la cadena:

```
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
   "Conexion": "Server =.;Initial Database=dbsistema;Integrated Security=Tr ue"  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Si voy al visual studio me muestra la conexión como se aprecia en la imagen:

[image: Cadena de conexión]

Pero me genera un error por consola y no me despliega el Json
[image: Error al verificar en la consola de Chrome]

Comment: Ese error no es de la conexion a la db, parece ser un error de la pagina. Podes decir si llegas a tu backend o no?

Comment: - gbianchi, cuando ejecuto la aplicación no despliega nada.

Comment: - gbianchi, cuando ejecuto la aplicación no despliega nada. No tengo certeza si hace algo a nível de backend, esta es la sintáxis de la  url para que despliegue el registro: // GET: api/Categorias

Comment: Si pones un punto de interrupcion en tu back, llega? probaste el back? te fijaste si la llamada la hace correctamente en la parte de red?

Comment: Me sale esto cuando depuro, al parecer si hay un problema con esa conexión   Message "Keyword not supported: 'initial database'." string y no he podido ver por ningun lado el id ni la descripción de la categoría.

Comment: Entonces esta mal la cadena de conexion.

Comment: gbianchi,  en la imagen tengo resaltado en amarillo la cadena que necesito, como quedaría definida.

Comment: La cadena de conexion no es esa. Es la que esta a la derecha en la ventana propiedades donde dice cadena de conexion.

Comment: gbianchi, Disculpa, es el servidor el resaltado en amarillo, la cadena es la del Json, como quedaría.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la forma correcta de la conexión:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Conexion":"Server=desarrollo;Database=dbsistema;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

}